# How to Apply Col Offset in Bootstrap 4 as it was in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I will be thankful if anyone can please tell me How to Apply Col Offset in Bootstrap 4 as it was possible earlier in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest and the best way is to check the bootstrap 4 css file.

I checked the CSS file here on [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

To apply offset you can use

`.offset-lg-*
.offset-sm-*
.offset-sm-*
.offset-xs-*
.offset-*`

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was very Helpful!